# Is there a way to visualize ongoing sessions/transaction on AWS QLDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-qldb

I want to know if there is any metric related to QLDB where I could monitor the active ongoing sessions/transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLDB doesn't have an Active Query List view like some databases, due to its 30 second transaction limits and PartiQL limits. However, you can use CloudWatch, or some similar logging tool to understand Read and Write IOs, processing time, `OccConflictExceptions`, and `SessionRateExceededExceptions` to understand how to tune connections.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html